# Overview of Google+ API error codes

Tags: google-api, google-plus

For a project of mine I need the error codes which different social network APIs will return. Until now I have the return codes of

- [Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/errors/)
- [Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/error-codes-responses)
- [Youtube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_error_responses)

Prominently missing here is the Google+ API. I found different error messages at different places, like the "Invalid field selection " message at the bottom of https://developers.google.com/+/api/

I also downloaded the .NET Google API Client and looked for error handling but found none.

**So my question is: Where do I find a (more or less) complete list of errors of the Google+ API found at https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1**

As suggested by [class](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1552344/class) I filed a issue on [code.google.com](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=635) for such a site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There currently is not a page I'm aware of that tracks all of the error codes and resolutions. There are some resources on the web that track general resolutions and errors:

- [Common problems with Google+ Sign-In on Android](http://www.riskcompletefailure.com/2013/03/common-problems-with-google-sign-in-on.html)
- [Common issues with Google+ Sign-In on iOS](http://www.riskcompletefailure.com/2013/06/common-issues-with-google-sign-in-on-ios.html)
- [Common issues and solutions for the new Google+ Platform release](http://gusclass.com/blog/2013/02/27/common-issues-for-the-new-google-platform-release/)
- [Even more common errors with Google+ Sign-In](http://gusclass.com/blog/2013/05/09/even-more-common-errors-with-sign-in/)

Please add or star an issue for documenting the error codes returned from the API here:

[Google+ GitHub Organization](https://github.com/googleplus)